# Bitmask to boolean conversion in the model

Tags: checkbox, extjs

I have a model that receives int bitmasks from the backend:

```
{"user": 7, "group":5, "other":1}
```

and I now want to show a form with checkboxes like this:

```
user:   [X] read [X] write [X] execute
group:  [X] read [ ] write [X] execute
other:  [ ] read [ ] write [X] execute
```

where user can toggle on or off and then the updated bitmask is sent back to the server in a `store.sync` operation.

I know how to make and align the checkboxes, but ExtJS checkboxes in a form bind to boolean values through a correlation between the checkbox `name` and the model field `name`, and not to parts of bitmask.

So I have to convert back and forth between the bitmask int and a bunch of booleans. How would I implement that in a reusable manner?

Comment: Did you try using [Ext.form.CheckboxGroup](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.form.CheckboxGroup.html)? It provides "methods for getting, setting, and validating the group of checkboxes as a whole."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the checkbox group component is a good candidate to render your checkboxes and also to implement the conversion logic.
Here is a reusable component to do the two-way conversion of bitmasks:

```
    Ext.define('Fiddle.Bitmask', {
        extend: 'Ext.form.CheckboxGroup',
        xtype: 'fiddlebitmask',

        isFormField: true,
        columns: 3,

        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'Read',
            name: 'read',
            inputValue: 1,
            excludeForm: true,
            uncheckedValue: 0
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Write',
            name: 'write',
            inputValue: 1,
            excludeForm: true,
            uncheckedValue: 0
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Execute',
            name: 'exec',
            inputValue: 1,
            excludeForm: true,
            uncheckedValue: 0
        }],
        getModelData: function () {
            let obj = {};
            obj[this.name] = this.getValue();
            return obj;
        },
        setValue: function (value) {
            if (value) {
                var binary = Ext.String.leftPad((value).toString(2), 3, '0');
                value = {
                    read: Number(binary[0]),
                    write: Number(binary[1]),
                    exec: Number(binary[2])
                };
            }
            this.callParent([value]);
        },
        getValue: function () {
            var value = this.callParent();
            var binary = `${value['read']||0}${value['write']||0}${value['exec']||0}`
            return parseInt(binary, 2);
        }
    });
```

And the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2clg

**edit** Component completed with *getModelData* implementation to support usage with *form.getValues/form.updateRecord*.

Comment: I have tested this but unfortunately, it does not work with `form.loadRecord` and `form.updateRecord` and it seems I cannot get it to work. https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2cgc

Comment: By default the form.getValues method (used by updateRecord) ignores the checkboxgroup components. I edited the component in order to work with the form as expected.

Answer (score 0):

What version of Ext are you using? If your version supports [ViewModels](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.app.ViewModel.html) then I would do the conversion in the ViewModel and bind it to the view.

There is the [convert](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.data.field.Field.html#method-convert) and [calculate](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.data.field.Field.html#cfg-calculate) config on fields as well but they are converting in one way only.